# How to create approval Workflow using prefect?

Tags: prefect

I have started work on prefect workflow in python and didn't find any help regarding to approval workflow.

Can anyone let me know how I'll be able to create approval workflows in prefect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of configuring an approval workflow in Prefect.

### Using a trigger

Triggers allow you to specify the state-based conditions required for your task to run; in the approval case, we can use a `manual_only` trigger so that every single time this task runs and its upstreams are complete, the task will enter a `Paused` state and wait for approval:

```py
from prefect import task, Flow
from prefect.triggers import manual_only

@task
def build():
    print("build task")
    return True

@task
def test(build_result):
    print("test task")
    build_result == True

@task(trigger=manual_only)
def deploy():
    """
    With the manual_only trigger this task will only run after it has been approved
    """
    print("deploy task")
    pass
    
with Flow("code_deploy") as flow:
    res = build()
    deploy(upstream_tasks=[test(res)])
```

Note that using triggers means that *every time* this flow run, the deploy task will wait for approval.

### Use a signal

Alternatively, we can gain some flexibility if we use a [Prefect Signal](https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/execution.html#state-signals); signals allow us to force task runs to enter certain states via a special type of exception.  In this case, we can pause and wait only when some condition is met:

```py
from prefect import task, Flow
from prefect.engine.signals import PAUSE

@task
def build():
    print("build task")
    return True

@task
def test(build_result):
    print("test task")
    build_result == True

@task
def deploy():
    """
    With the manual_only trigger this task will only run after it has been approved
    """
    print("deploy task")
    if some_condition:
        raise PAUSE("Condition met - waiting for approval.")
    pass

with Flow("code_deploy") as flow:
    res = build()
    deploy(upstream_tasks=[test(res)])
```

This allows for more fine-grained control of when the pause occurs and even how long it occurs (you can specify a `start_time` when you initialize the `PAUSE` signal so that no manual intervention is necessary).

More resources:

- [Blog Post](https://medium.com/the-prefect-blog/needs-approval-184f2512a3cf)
- [Idiom in the documentation](https://docs.prefect.io/core/idioms/pause-for-approval.html#pause-for-approval)